# Flatten a Multidimensional Array with key, value and object from a JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

For 2 days, I'm trying to extract informations from a multidimensional array and I think I'm stuck after trying a lot of things

Here is my json

```
{
  "profile": [
    {
      "id": "123456",
      "hostId": null,
      "description": [
        {
          "id": "name",
          "value": "foo"
        },
        {
          "id": "name2",
          "value": "foo2"
        },
        {
          "id": "bio",
          "value": "heyyyy"
        },
        {
          "id": "location",
          "value": "somewhere"
        }
      ],
      "ishere": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to manipulate it to have this

```
{
  "id": "123456",
  "host": null,
  "name": "foo",
  "name2": "foo2",
  "bio": "heyyyy",
  "location": "somewhere",
  "ishere": true
}
```

with this (after a json_decode)

```
        foreach ($array->profileUsers[0]->settings as $item) {
            $out2[$item->id] = $item->value;
        }
```

I only have

```
{  
  "name": "foo",
  "name2": "foo2",
  "bio": "heyyyy",
  "location": "somewhere"
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `I want to kill myself after trying a lot of things` Easy on, that certainly won't format your array for you. What was involved in the other ways have you tried? Loops? json_decode()? Which of your attempts came the closest to what you want to do, even if it didn't work? Edit your question with any code you tried but didn't work and it'll be easier to help you towards what you want.

Comment: Were you able to convert the json-array (first block) to a php-array? That would make it easier...

Comment: There'is no problem to do a json_decode and json_encode in the end. But  it's between that it's difficult for me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$obj = json_decode($your_json);
$obj = $obj->profile[0];
foreach($obj->description as $d)
    $obj->{$d->id} = $d->value;
unset($obj->description);
```

Comment: Juste one thing ""ishere": true" is not at the right place now. It's not at the end but just before the ex items from description.

Comment: @Alex: normally, the position doesn't matter. Why do you care?

Comment: Because I reproduce an existing API myself and try to have the exactly result than the original one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode($your_json, true);
$new_array = [];
foreach($data['profile'] as $key=>$item) {
  if(is_array($item)) {
     $new_array[$item['id']] = $item['value'];
  }
  else {
     $new_array[$key] = $item;
  }
}
```

Hardcoded this, hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, but "id", "host", "ishere" can be other things or I can have more items ...